# Flutter: BlocBuilder always builds despite buildWhen returning false

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to display a widget based on a condition inside my `Bloc`

For some strange reason, my `BlocBuilder` will always build despite `buildWhen` returning false.

**Even with this rediculous example, the bloc will build!**

```html
BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyBlocState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => false, // builds anyway!
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const Text(
            'data',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I don't want to wrap my widget with a `Visibility` widget.. That's what `buildWhen` is for..

**Note:** there's nothing above my widget that may be causing this, and this isn't my first time using this bloc functionality, so this is extremely weird!

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Just to make sure: `BlocBuilder.builder` is called at least one time, since it is added to widget tree. So, `buildWhen` is used from the second time onwards. When you say "the bloc will build!", do you mean, the second time that a state is emitted too or just the first emit?

Comment: @Luis Felipe de Almeida daSilva that's such a subtle distinction! I didn't know it was always going to build on the first time, and to your point, yes, I did mean it's built on the first time.

Comment: Yeah. For me this is not explicit explained on the doc. So if you don't want to use `Visibility` widget, you may use `if (conditionHere) BlocBuilder(...)`